# How to prove by contradiction

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am asked to prove: If $a-\epsilon< b$ for every $\epsilon> 0$, then $a \le b$.

I have worked out that a proof by contradiction, assume $a>b$, would be best in this case but I am not too sure where to proceed from there. Should I rearrange the first part I am given? Must I pick a specific epsilon?

Comment: If $a > b$, then $a - \frac{a-b}{2} > b$, and $\frac{a-b}{2}>0$.

Comment: "Must I pick a specific epsilon"  You must pick an epsilon where this fails.  So pick an epsilon where $a - \epsilon \ge b$.  To find such an epsilon solve $a \ge b + \epsilon$ and $a - b \ge \epsilon$.  If $a > b$ any epsilon equal or less than $a -b$ will do.  For simplicity use $\epsilon = a-b$.

Comment: @fleablood I thought to use e=a-b but I am not to sure where to go from there. Would I then have to plug it into my assumption of a-e<b?

Comment: If e = a-b then a - e = b, but that contradicts our hypothesis that a- e < b for ***all*** e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to get inspiration in how to do a proof by contradiction:

We know we want:

Step 1:  $a \not \le b$

Step 2: $a > b$

Step 3: ?????????

Step 4: $a - \epsilon \ge b$  (Profit!)

So what's step 3?

Work back from step 4:

$a - \epsilon \ge b$

$a - b \ge \epsilon$

$a- b \ge \epsilon > 0$

$a - b > 0$ so

$a > b$

Step 2:

So proof is:

Suppose $a \not \le b$

$a > b$

$a-b > 0$.  Select any $\epsilon$ so that $a-b \ge \epsilon > 0$

Then $a-\epsilon \ge b$.  A contradiction.

=====

To do it mostly directly with a hail-mary proof by contradiction at the end.

$a - \epsilon < b$ for all $\epsilon$ means

$a - b < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$.

$\epsilon$ can be *any* positive number.

If $a-b > 0$ then if $\epsilon = a-b$ we have

$a-b < \epsilon = a -b$.  Impossible.

So $a - b \le 0$ and $a \le b$.

======

$a - \epsilon < b$ means $a -b < \epsilon$ means $a -b$ is less then all positive numbers.

The proof hinges on the observation that *only 0 and negative numbers are smaller than all positive numbers*.  This is because no positive number is less than itself.

So here is proof number umpteen:

$0 < a - b < a-b = \epsilon$ is impossible.

So it can't be that $a - \epsilon < a- \epsilon =b$ for $\epsilon = a-b$.

But $a - \epsilon < b$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

So that must mean $\epsilon = a-b > 0$ is impossible.

The only way that is impossible, as $\epsilon $ can be any positive number, is that $a-b$ is not positive.

$a - b \le 0$.

And $a \le b$.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof** (by contradiction). Assume that $a-\epsilon<b$ for every $\epsilon>0$ and suppose $a>b$. Take $\epsilon_0=a-b$. Then $\epsilon_0>0$. Using the assumption (as $\epsilon_0$ is a specific value of $\epsilon$), we get
$$a-\epsilon_0<b.$$
We get
 $$a-(a-b)<b$$
implying $$b<b,$$ contradicting to the fact that $b=b$ (see the Trichotomy Law). Hence, $a\leq b$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that a>b.

You are given that $\forall\epsilon>0,$ $a-\epsilon <b,$ so to derive a contradiction, you must establish the existence of an $\epsilon$ such that $a-\epsilon \ge b.$ Since $a>b,$ $$\epsilon = (a-b) >0$$ and it fits the bill since $a-\epsilon = b \ge b.$